# Displaying a png image from base64 data

Tags: angularjs, base64, png

We are printing labels, which are created by a third party. We serve them directly, passing the base64 data into a blank window, so the user can print it himself.

No matter how many ways I try it, I cannot get the image itself to display.

Here's an excerpt of the data returned from the server (in any other display, it is full of � characters):

```
PNG


IHDR,Â_gbásRGB®ÎégAMA±üa    pHYs88?'õÿ¥IDATx^ì½ ÅöÏî÷íþ÷Û½×T$$1`ÎY130b@ ÂQ@%T8äs<d1¢sÆ|õÞëÝ÷_ÏÛSÓÍP}fúLO'ßßÝg'õtWÕTc=ç­·ª   3*Ub%$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmâü«$ÓÍí$×MôqÝn!þîmü 4¥B!ÿ*  ü¼¹£Fë&@ú¸n7    L÷¶I~P©R1«PÈ¿Jà?oî¨äº   >n£ÛÂM ÄÓ½mWb
ùWI<àçÍ5\7AÒÇmt[¸Iøcº·MòBIYêIÀÈ¿JàÜÜq!Éu }ÜF·A?¦{Û$/U*¢JÅ¥¤þ¯ 9+È¿JàÜÜq!Éu }ÜF·A?¦{Û$O¨ÿ+¢bþn1D]
xÁº¹cBë&@ú¸n7   L÷¶I!bÎ[)FÔ¥¨s)Ô1ùWI<ßÍm\7AÒÇmt[¸Iøcº·Mª(ð&0(±BX%*bÙSÆüDþUä{sG$×MôqÝn!þîm¼ M
¢)ªTR¥¤¨OÃt1Èºøûïü«$¨ÈÍ\7AÒÇmt[¸Iøcº·Mò6)0$¼q)ö^1Íó7Ä"ÿ*    *rsÇ$×MôqÝn!þîm¼` ×SuI=
¹¹ãBë&@ú¸n7 L÷¶IÙ@ü$W
ùWI<ëÍG\7AÒÇmt[¸Iøcº·MÊOËQBþUäzsÇ$×MôqÝn!þîm²i`¹ªPÈ¿Jà\oî8äº    >n£ÛÂM ÄÓ½mRÁqº¹½äº >n£ÛÂM ÄÓ½mR6L¹*n*ò¯ x ×;$¹n¤Ûè¶p ñÇto
S®
ü«$Èõæ#I® éã
```

etc. etc.

This is what I'm trying to do with it - with various false starts:

```
    vm.getLabelBinaryData = function (labelId){
        labelsService.getShippingLabel(labelId).then (
            function success(response) {
                vm.openWindowForLabels(response.data);
            },
            function fail(response) {
                toastr.error(response.data);
            }
        );
    };
    vm.openWindowForLabels = function (responseData) {
        //var b64Response = btoa(rawResponse)
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + responseData;
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1000,height=1000');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><head></head><body></body></html>');
        popupWin.document.body.appendChild(image);  
        //popupWin.document.close();
    };
```

When I inspect the HTML, I see this:

```
<html><head></head><body><img src="data:image/png;base64,�PNG&#13;&#10;&#10;
```

Strangely, in my browser window, I see the closing img bracket, and closing body and html tags. The fact that it didn;t copy leads em to  believe the data is either to long 'too long to edit', or some special character is killing it before it displays.

Either way, I get a broken image icon.

I'm stumped.

**UPDATE:**

I found a sample here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
so I plugged than in to my code:

```
    image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
```

...and it indeed shows the red dot just fine.

This strongly suggests that my code is working fine and that the problems lies with parsing the data properly. (I have verified with the API dev that he is seeing a working image in POSTMAN.)

Comment: I notice that the REAL data looks nothing like the SAMPLE data. Sample data is constrained to A-z...

Comment: Your data (PNG.... IHDR...) isn't base64; it's just a regular PNG datastream.

Comment: have you tried encoding the responseData to base64 yourself? `var imageData = btoa(responseData)`

Comment: @Glenn. Yes, this is what I've concluded. So the problem's at the sending end. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just removing the ";base64," from your "image src=...." line?